# Python: finding keys with unique values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I receive a dictionary as input, and want to return a list of keys for which the dictionary values are unique in the scope of that dictionary.

I will clarify with an example. Say my input is dictionary a, constructed as follows:

```
a = dict()
a['cat'] =      1
a['fish'] =     1
a['dog'] =      2  # <-- unique
a['bat'] =      3
a['aardvark'] = 3
a['snake'] =    4  # <-- unique
a['wallaby'] =  5
a['badger'] =   5
```

The result I expect is `['dog', 'snake']`.

There are obvious brute force ways to achieve this, however I wondered if there's a neat Pythonian way to get the job done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think efficient way if dict is too large would be

```
countMap = {}
for v in a.itervalues():
    countMap[v] = countMap.get(v,0) + 1
uni = [ k for k, v in a.iteritems() if countMap[v] == 1]
```

Comment: It would be prettier with collections.defaultdict(int), IMO

Comment: yes, but I would leave it so that people know what we use to do when there were no defaultdicts

Answer (score 6):

Note that this actually is a bruteforce:

```
l = a.values()
b = [x for x in a if l.count(a[x]) == 1]
```

Comment: it will not output ['dog', 'snake']

Comment: Isn't l.count('dog') zero?  l is [3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 5] on my system.

Comment: ok, i see that cobbal has already corrected the code. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that only requires traversing the dict once:

```
def unique_values(d):
    seen = {} # dict (value, key)
    result = set() # keys with unique values
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if v in seen:
            result.discard(seen[v])
        else:
            seen[v] = k
            result.add(k)
    return list(result)
```

Comment: If a value occurs 3 times, you will try to remove a non-existent element from `result` ... docs say """remove(elem) 
Remove element elem from the set. Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set."""

Comment: Right you are!  I have corrected it to use discard() instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> b = []
>>> import collections
>>> bag = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> for v in a.itervalues():
...     bag[v] += 1
...
>>> b = [k for (k, v) in a.iteritems() if bag[v] == 1]
>>> b.sort() # optional
>>> print b
['dog', 'snake']
>>>
```

Comment: @Ryan: True but `lambda: 0` is more explicit than `int` ... AFAICT, until defaultdict arrived [2.5], the number of persons who knew that int() produced 0 [since 2.2] instead of an exception was < epsilon and the number who had a use for that knowledge was even smaller :-)

Answer (score 2):

A little more verbose, but does need only one pass over a:

```
revDict = {}
for k, v in a.iteritems():
  if v in revDict:
     revDict[v] = None
  else:
     revDict[v] = k

[ x for x in revDict.itervalues() if x != None ]
```

( I hope it works, since I can't test it here )

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the dictionary keys is None. For example if a is {None: 1} the output should be [None] but the above code will produce []. Also: `x is not None` is preferable to `x != None`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! You are totally right. In praxis, it seldom happens that None is used ... but even then, one could create some DummyObject: "Dummy = object()" instead of using None.

Answer (score 2):

What about subclassing?

```
class UniqueValuesDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, *args)
        self._inverse = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value in self.values():
            if value in self._inverse:
                del self._inverse[value]
        else:
            self._inverse[value] = key
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def unique_values(self):
        return self._inverse.values()

a = UniqueValuesDict()

a['cat'] =      1
a['fish'] =     1
a[None] =       1
a['duck'] =     1
a['dog'] =      2  # <-- unique
a['bat'] =      3
a['aardvark'] = 3
a['snake'] =    4  # <-- unique
a['wallaby'] =  5
a['badger'] =   5

assert a.unique_values() == ['dog', 'snake']
```

Comment: This has the advantage of a smaller memory footprint, but you end up doing an O(N) search every time you set an item, so it's liable to be a lot slower than the dictionary tabulation method. Also, I think you could use a set for _inverse instead of a dict.

Comment: Another problem: the OP placed no constraints on how the contents of the dict were obtained. So one would expect that `del a['bat']; print a.unique_values()` would cause `aardvark` to appear in the output but sadly it doesn't and fixing that would require even more convolutions and __double__underscores__ :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation.

```
>>> import collections
>>> inverse= collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in a.items():
...     inverse[v].append(k)
... 
>>> [ v[0] for v in inverse.values() if len(v) == 1 ]
['dog', 'snake']
```

I'm partial to this because the inverted dictionary is such a common design pattern.

Comment: You want [ v[0] for k,v ...] in the last line to get ['dog', 'snake'] as requested.

Comment: (1) Instead of .items(), use .iteritems(). (2) The last line extracts the key needlessly; should be `[v[0] for v in inverse.itervalues() if len(v) == 1` (3) In any case building the whole inverted dict is overkill.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this (just count the number of occurrences for each value):

```
def unique(a):
    from collections import defaultdict
    count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for k, v in a.iteritems():
        count[v] += 1
    for v, c in count.iteritems():
        if c <= 1:
            yield v
```

Comment: This is yielding values (2, 4) when it should yield keys ('dog', 'snake').

Comment: I find `defaultdict(int)` to be a bit more clear than `defaultdict(lambda:0)`.  Since a default dict of almost any other type will simply use the type name.

Answer (score -2):

Use nested list comprehensions!

```
print [v[0] for v in 
           dict([(v, [k for k in a.keys() if a[k] == v])
                     for v in set(a.values())]).values()
       if len(v) == 1]
```

Comment: I don't see how using list comprehensions in this way is a win. For me, this just makes the solution  harder to comprehend (no pun intended). Readability is key and this solution is just not that readable IMO.

Comment: Rax asked for "a neat Pythonian way to get the job done," as opposed to "obvious" solutions to an otherwise trivial problem.

Comment: (1) Use `k in a` instead of `k in a.keys()` (2) Use `whatever.itervalues()` instead of `whatever.values()` (3) The dict(yadda yadda) part is building the already-overkill inverse of `a` inefficiently (4) It's neither neat nor Python(ic|ian) ... but it's certainly not obvious! (5) Count the number of responders whose first effort at the so-called trivial problem was a stuff-up.

Comment: This `solution` can be edited (using only the delete key!) to get rid of building the inverse; still O(N^2) though: `print [v[0] for v in [[k for k in a if a[k] == v] for v in set(a.values())] if len(v) == 1]`