# Finding if there are distinct elements in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a python dictionary containing n key-value pairs, out of which n-1 values are identical and 1 is not. I need to find the key of the distinct element.

For example: consider a python list `[{a:1},{b:1},{c:2},{d:1}]`. I need the to get `'c'` as the output.

I can use a for loop to compare consecutive elements and then use two more for loops to compare those elements with the other elements. But is there a more efficient way to go about it or perhaps a built-in function which I am unaware of?

Comment: I could find the answer with a slight modification of this code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032281/python-finding-keys-with-unique-values-in-a-dictionary

Comment: If n-1 values are identical, you only need one for loop. As soon as you see two values that are different, you know which one it is.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Good point -- although if the unique one is one of the first two you won't know which one it is until you see the third element.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yes indeed! That was a caveat I thought of after I posted that comment...

Comment: Your description (a dict) doesn't match your example (a list of dictionaries, each containing one key/value.)

Comment: This seems like an atypical application of a `dict`. I wonder if maybe there's a more appropriate data structure.  Do you mind if I ask what the context of the problem is?

Comment: @skatenerd basically I have a dict coming from identical different servers and assumption is that all of them except 1 have correct data. I am required to detect the error data and correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dictionary you can quickly check and find the first value which is different from the next two values cycling around the keys of your dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
def find_different(d):
    k = d.keys()
    for i in xrange(0, len(k)):
        if d[k[i]] != d[k[(i+1)%len(k)]] and d[k[i]] != d[k[(i+2)%len(k)]]:
            return k[i]

>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':1}
>>> find_different(mydict)
'c'
```

Otherwise, if what you have is a list of single-key dictionaries, then you can do it quite nicely mapping your list with a function which "extracts" the values from your elements, then check each one using the same logic.

Here's another working example:

```
def find_different(l):
    mask = map(lambda x: x[x.keys()[0]], l)
    for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        if mask[i] != mask[(i+1)%len(l)] and mask[i] != mask[(i+2)%len(l)]:
            return l[i].keys()[0]

>>> mylist = [{'a':1},{'b':1},{'c':2},{'d':1}]
>>> find_different(mylist)
'c'
```

**NOTE**: these solutions do not work in Python 3 as the `map` function doesn't return a `list` and neither does the `.keys()` method of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "list of pairs" (actually list of dictionaries, *sigh*) cannot be changed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_pair(d):
    return (d.keys()[0], d.values()[0])

def extract_unique(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in map(get_pair, l):
        d[value].append(key)
    return filter(lambda (v,l): len(l) == 1, d.items())[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your dictionary, then you make a list of all of the keys:  `key_list = yourDic.keys()`.  Using that list, you can then loop through your dictionary.  This is easier if you know one of the values, but below I assume that you do not.

```
yourDic = {'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':1, 'd':1, }
key_list = yourDic.keys()
previous_value = yourDic[key_list[0]] # Making it so loop gets past first test
count = 0
for key in key_list:
    test_value = yourDic[key]
    if (test_value != previous_value) and count == 1: # Checks first key
        print key_list[count - 1]
        break
    elif (test_value != previous_value):
        print key
        break
    else:
        previous_value = test_value
        count += 1
```

So, once you find the value that is different, it will print the key.  If you want it to print the value, too, you just need a `print test_value` statement

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels: first of all, the OP didn't talk about a dictionary, but about a list of dictionaries; then you are checking every item with its right sibling, so if the different element is the first one in the list your method will not identify it correctly.

Comment: I copy and pasted a previous one.  It's already been fixed.  Oh, and the OP's example hasa a list, but specifically asked about "python dictionary containing n key-value pairs," and the title of the question specifically mentions a dictionary, so that is the question I answered